# Javascript click function is not working on first click

Tags: javascript

I have created a function that adds an active class on click its works fine but it's not adding an active class on the first click on the second click its start working fine. here is my code

```js
  function howAppWorks($imgUrl, $myClass, event) {
                document.getElementById('myImage').src = $imgUrl;
                document.getElementById("howTheAppContent").classList.remove('addEvent', 'fillTheForm', 'rrtFlowSheet');
                document.getElementById("howTheAppContent").classList.add($myClass);
    
                // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
                var header = document.getElementById("appWorksList");
                var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("custom-class");
    
                for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
                    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
                        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
                        this.className += " active";
                    });
                }
    
            }
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="howTheAppWorksContent addEvent" id="howTheAppContent">
                    <img id="myImage" src="http://localhost/projects/rrs-website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/how-the-app-works.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="appWorksList">
            <table>
                <tr class='custom-class active' id="addEvent" onclick="howAppWorks('http:\/\/localhost/projects/rrs-website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/how-the-app-works.png', 'addEvent')">
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='custom-class' onclick="howAppWorks('http:\/\/localhost/projects/rrs-website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/fill-the-forms.png', 'fillTheForm')">
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='custom-class' onclick="howAppWorks('http:\/\/localhost/projects/rrs-website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/rrt-flow-sheet.png', 'rrtFlowSheet')">
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why don't you bind the handlers initially if you don't want to bind them **after** the first click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your logic.
You are calling an `onclick` and then in that `onclick` you are registering an event on the same `buttons`. It is better to do one thing, or simply take out `event listener` outside the `howAppWorks` function. Like this:

```js
function howAppWorks($imgUrl, $myClass, event) {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = $imgUrl;
  document.getElementById("howTheAppContent").classList.remove('addEvent', 'fillTheForm', 'rrtFlowSheet');
  document.getElementById("howTheAppContent").classList.add($myClass);

  // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)


}
var header = document.getElementById("appWorksList");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("custom-class");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="howTheAppWorksContent addEvent" id="howTheAppContent">
        <img id="myImage" src="http://localhost/projects/rrs-website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/how-the-app-works.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" id="appWorksList">
    <table>
      <tr class='custom-class active' id="addEvent" onclick="howAppWorks('http:\/\/localhost/projects/rrs-website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/how-the-app-works.png', 'addEvent')">
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='custom-class' onclick="howAppWorks('http:\/\/localhost/projects/rrs-website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/fill-the-forms.png', 'fillTheForm')">
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='custom-class' onclick="howAppWorks('http:\/\/localhost/projects/rrs-website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/rrt-flow-sheet.png', 'rrtFlowSheet')">
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/h0xrmugc/)

Comment: @AtifAzad Fi Amanillah